# Identify raster cell values with a polygon or a raster layer on top in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, identify

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

How do I identify values in raster cells while there is a polygon or another raster layer on top with the Explore-tool?

I don't need to select any values, and I also don't need a table or another layer with the values. I need to identify individual values by clicking. Example use cases would be

1. if I need to see a study area boundaries (polygon) on top of a raster layer and identify a few cell values on the fly, or
2. if I have a raster layer, that has no-value cells, on top and I need to know the cell values in the raster below exactly where the no-value cells are, and not all of them, only in a small area.

I know that saving a polygon as a line would be one way but I'm interested in learning a way to do this without changing the layers (keeping them as polygons and rasters).

I have tried the Clip Layers and Clip to an outline -tool in the Map Properties to solve the problem #1 but it doesn't work when I still want to see all the data outside the study area. I have also tried using the List by Selection and unselecting the layer on top and then selecting Selectable Layers from the Explore-tool, but the tool doesn't give me any values in this case (Identifying-window pops up but nothing after it).

Answer (score 1):

Click the dropdown arrow that's part of the [Explore tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.1/help/mapping/navigation/pop-ups.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_85E0F9F1E4D2408A8EF2F10A6F7A051B) button n the ribbon and change the popup option to either:

- **Visible Layers** — Only layers currently visible return pop-ups.
- **Selected in Contents** — Only layers currently selected in the Contents pane return pop-ups.

[image]

You can also change the [polygon layer symbology](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.1/help/mapping/layer-properties/polygon-symbols.htm) to remove the fill and show just the polygon borders.